# How to set a specific name for a specific chunk with webpack while using hash for other chunks?

Tags: webpack, vue-cli

In my application, i'm using a lazy-loaded module using :

`import(/* webpackChunkName: "settings" */ './settings')`

Webpack's outputs are configured like this :

```
output: {
    filename: '[name].[hash:8].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].[contenthash:8].js',
  }
```

But, when i deploy my app, a script is responsible to override some informations in the settings.js file previously builded.

*I know that i could delete the [contenthash], but i need to keep it for vendors chunk.*

**How could i say to webpack "If you see the settings chunk, don't append the contenthash to his name" ?**

Answer (score -1):

As stated in the comment below - it is not possible at the moment to supply a function for `chunkFilename` (previous answer).

You can however use the [WebpackAssetManifestPlugin](https://github.com/webdeveric/webpack-assets-manifest) to create a manifest file with a map of the original chunk name (settings) and the hashed version.

Your deploy script would need to read this manifest file first.

Comment: at the moment chunkFilename doesn't accept a function.